# Как ввести в один массив множество строк?

Tags: python, python-3.x

В задание надо ввести много строчик слов в один массив, в при этом в последней строчке ничего нету что бы закончил цикл. Я хз как это делать сижу ломаю голову, так еще там там первое строчка и должно выйти как название команды, Пример:

```
  Ivanovs Team
  Ivanov
  Ivanov
  Ivanov
```

и должно выйти:
 `Ivanovs Team: Ivanov, Ivanov, Ivanov.`  Помогите пж

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import re

text = """  Ivanovs Team
  Ivanov
  Ivanov
  Ivanov"""

title, *team=re.findall(r'\w+ Team|\w+', text)

var = f'{title}: ' + ', '.join(team)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"в при этом в последней строчке ничего нету что бы закончил цикл".
 Цикл прервется если ничего не вводить.    
 array = []
 while True:
    string = input('Введите слово: ')
    if string != '':
      array.append(string)
    else:
      print(array)
      break
```

Comment: `и должно выйти:  Ivanovs Team: Ivanov, Ivanov, Ivanov. `

Comment: Ага, ясно не понял условия задачи.

Comment: Сам так часто лажаю )))